# Which compound releases more energy upon combustion?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I know that the last two on the right are stable so they are not the answer, but can someone give me a hint on how to decide between the two on the left? what is the way of solving such question, I don't think it's only dependent on stability because there is more ring strain (two cyclobutanes) in the molecule at far left.

Comment: How do you decide stability, to begin with?

Comment: well usually comparing different rings, the smaller the ring, the higher the strain and less stable it is. but here I'm comparing cyclooctane which is less stable than cyclohexane, but comparing the last two confused me two cyclobutanes connected vs cyclooctane.@IvanNeretin

Comment: At a glance I assumed they were all isomers, but they are not. I'm not sure whether this makes the answer harder or easier.

Comment: The very left one has 2 rings and therefore 2 less hydrogens. The rest 3 are isomers. So the answer depends on if the molar or specific combustion enthalpy is to be considered, wrt to the C-C and C-H bond energies.

Comment: First of all, great notice matt, but it makes it harder for me, there no specific enthalpies given in this question, (it's a question from an exam in 2017 btw, I'm not a student anymore). so i am not sure if it is related to these 2 hydrogens or not.

Comment: There is practically no strain in the cyclooctane, as the molecule is not in a plane. The Carbon atoms are all tetrahedra.

Comment: so why is it answer? what is the logic?